# Convert ntext to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of my column is defined as `ntext` datatype which is no longer supported by many streams. I'm trying my best to convert that column to numeric or int and every attempt is reaching anywhere.

```
reg_no #my ntext field | name | country | etc |
```

I tried to alter the col using the command we all use, but failed

```
alter table tabl1
    alter column [reg_no] numeric(38,0)
```

Error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Any suggestions on fixing this or has anyone come across this in the past, if yes how did you get over it

Comment: What do you mean "failed"? Did you get an error message? What was it? Have you checked that all the existing values in the column are numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this in two steps:

```
alter table tabl1 alter column [reg_no] nvarchar(max);
alter table tabl1 alter column [reg_no] numeric(38,0);
```

`ntext` is deprecated and conversion to `numeric` is not supported, but converting to `nvarchar()` is supported.

This assumes that the values are compatible with `numeric`.  Otherwise you will get a type conversion error.  If this happens, you can get the offending values by using:

```
select *
from t
where try_convert(numeric(38, 0), try_convert(nvarchar(max), x)) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

select convert(int,convcert(varchar(40), reg_no)) as newfieldname from tabl1